# ffmpeg add loop to this line of code i have

Tags: ffmpeg

the code itself is working fine however the 2.mp3 finishes instead i will like it to just loop all the way keeping the current settings how it is as I am happy with it

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\vaastav song .mp4" -i "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\2.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=3000|60000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix" -vcodec copy -y "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\output1.mp4"
```

Comment: Anyone please a simple loop to mp3

Comment: amazing....... nobody

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\vaastav song .mp4" -stream_loop -1 -i "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\2.mp3" -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=3000|60000[1a];[0:a][1a]amix=duration=first" -vcodec copy -y "C:\Users\test\Desktop\vidz\New folder (2)\target\output1.mp4"`